# Method multipartFormRequestWithMethod of AFURLRequestSerialization in iOS 8 doesn't work

Tags: ios, afnetworking-2

I have a problem : try app on iOS 8 and find that method multipartFormRequestWithMethod of AFURLRequestSerialization in iOS 8 doesn't work. In iOS 7 it works correct.

AFHTTPRequestOperation fail with timeout error if i send constructingBodyWithBlock parameter (i send block the same way as it do in tutorial).

Does anybody have the same issue?

I will be glad if you share with me some ideas, how resolve this problem.

Comment: Problem was resolved with new version AFNetworking
issue closed)